# How to consume data from an Express route to a React Router route

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, react-router, http-status-codes

I have an express route which is hit after nodemailer sends a confirmation email to a user.

```
router.route('/confirmation/:token').get((req, res, next) => {
  try {
    Token.findOne({ token: req.params.token }, function(err, token) {
      if (err)
        return res.status(404).send({
          type: 'not-verified',
          msg: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.'
        });
      // If we found a token, find a matching user
      User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, email: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
          return res
            .status(404)
            .send({ msg: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });
        if (user.isVerified)
          return res.status(400).send({
            type: 'already-verified',
            msg: 'This user has already been verified.'
          });

        // Verify and save the user
        user.isVerified = true;
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
          }
          return res
            .status(200)
            .send({
              msg: [
                'The account has been verified. Please log in.',
                { userVerified: user.isVerified }
              ]
            })
            .redirect('/login');
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Email:

> Hello, Please verify your account by clicking the link:
>   http://localhost:8016/users/confirmation/a217ba992e977079eeeca541677fedcb

Naturally and expectingly it takes me to: `http://localhost:8016/users/confirmation/a217ba992e977079eeeca541677fedcb`

And get as a response:

```
{
  "msg": [
  "The account has been verified. Please log in.",
  {
   "userVerified": true
  }
 ]
}
```

But what I want is to consume this data via React router. To make a modal or other component make use of it. Essentially get that data to fuel my routes on the client.

Something like:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location, props }) =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

  <PrivateRoute path={`/users/confirmation/${params.token}`}>
    {
      <Modal
        isAlertModal={false}
        history={history}
        affirmativeUsed="Yes"
        message="You have now completed your registration!"
        modalActive={true}
      />
    }
  </PrivateRoute>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how it works. Hit the /confirmation endpoint in one of your React components and then store the result in the Redux store. Then, connect any React component that needs access to that token to the Redux store.